# Does malware beacon in regular intervals or irregular intervals?

Tags: malware

I am trying to build a malware beaconing to C2 detection mechanism. One point of discussion is whether
- Malware communicates in frequent even spaced time intervals (Ex: Every 10 seconds to its C2 site). 
- Or irregular time intervals (Ex: First beacon at 2 seconds, then next at 5, next at 18, next at 56 and so on).

From reading/Googling various docs and looking at incident investigations, it seems to be both. However I am looking for some advice/pointers on the following dilemma

What is the downside in terms of malware coverage if I just build for regular intervals at this moment (First release) and then focus on irregular intervals later ?

Answer (score 1):

> From reading/Googling various docs and looking at incident investigations, it seems to be both. However I am looking for some advice/pointers on the following dilemma.

As you said, it's probably both. It may even depend on the mode the malware enters; it may enter sleep mode waiting for some event or date.

And there's many kinds of malware, from many different people, with many different goals. A cryptolocker for instance only needs to call home once; to communicate a key an ID number. A botnet participant will call home regularly to receive new commands; it may even open a persistent TCP connection. E.g. IRC has been used as a control channel previously.

A catch all-answer is clearly impossible.

In addition, there's lots of legitimate traffic occurring automatically, on fixed or variable times. Software updates, NTP, e-mail, etc.

> What is the downside in terms of malware coverage if I just build for regular intervals at this moment (First release) and then focus on irregular intervals later ?

This probably depends on what other characteristics you're looking for to decide if it's legitimate traffic. It's a complex question, and I believe it's impossible to judge, with the amount of information given.

Comment: Your "answer" gives absolutely no information ! And the OPis  trying to build a malware beaconing to C2 detection mechanism, so he "probably knows"  that IRC has been used as a CC and legitimate softwares..get updated :)

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri Feel free to suggest a better answer for the question.

Comment: I think this answer accurately states that the question is almost impossible to accurately and authoritatively answer.

Comment: @Cowthulhu It may be answerable given a lot more details, but as it stands now I fail to see how. I'm very open to being proven wrong though :)

Comment: Thanks, folks for jumping in to answer. Here is a bit more context. I have to build a detection mechanism specifically for Beaconing, but building one for regular intervals seems straight forward enough, but building for irregular intervals will need a design change that will take up time. At this point, I don't have data to say one way or the other. So I was hoping for group-mind on whether the majority of malware today uses regular intervals or irregular intervals. Usually, we always have deadlines to meet, but I want to ensure we build it right.

Comment: Also please assume, I will account for beaconing in legitimate traffic. Example: I will look for rare domains/IPs over a period of time among other things to refine my detection. So my question is mainly around the trade-offs around building both regular and irregular detection mechanisms at the same time.

Comment: Totally agree @vidarlo